# Rolling mean of correlation matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have to calculate the rolling mean of the correlation matrix. I did this

```
df_corr = df.rolling(window=3).corr()
```

but now I want to have

```
    2017-06-05 00:00:00+02:00 NaN

    2017-06-06 00:00:00+02:00 NaN

    2017-06-07 00:00:00+02:00 0.86
...
```

Where I evaluate the mean of the upper-right matrix (excluding diagonal).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you are a Ruby user. We pandas folks like data a lot. Please post a few rows so we can help (no screenshots). This helps for a reproducible example which as an avid SO owner you already know the concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is to apply a mask to the correlation matrix at each date, like below:

[image]

You can use [`numpy.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) with the parameter `k=1`.  This returns the indices for the upper-triangle of an (n, m) array; setting `k=1` ignores the diagonal.  So, to create a mask:

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.triu_indices(df_corr.shape[1], k=1)
    # .shape[1] = 4; each correl. matrix is 4x4
```

Now compute an average, ignoring masked values, for each period:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = df_corr.index.get_level_values(0)
avgs = [df_corr.loc[date].values[mask].mean() 
        for date in dates]
s = pd.Series(avgs, index=dates) # may want to dropna

print(s.tail())
Date
2017-07-03    0.72991
2017-07-04    0.73963
2017-07-04    0.73963
2017-07-04    0.73963
2017-07-04    0.73963
dtype: float64
```

To manually confirm the above you could inspect with:

```
df_corr.loc['2017-07-04'].values[mask]
Out[108]: 
array([ 0.72585007,  0.93792149,  0.79828102,  0.4422102 ,  0.99371595,
        0.53982374])

df_corr.loc['2017-07-04'].values[mask].mean()
Out[109]: 0.73963374659063508
```